# Horrible Flickering drawing in C#

Tags: c#, drawing

Anyone have any suggestions on how to stop this drawing from flickering? I have tried each double buffering solution, stopped using .CreateGraphics, moved all of my functions all over the place, nothing has worked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;


namespace Math
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Random rand = new Random();
    ProblemBox[] problems = new ProblemBox[20];
    #region Types

    public enum Type
    {
        Basic, Algebric, Triginomic
    }
    public class Problem
    {
        public Type type;
        public String problem, answer;
        public Boolean isTrue;
        public Problem(Type type, String problem, String answer, Boolean isTrue)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.problem = problem;
            this.answer = answer;
            this.isTrue = isTrue;
        }

    }


    class ProblemBox
    {
        public Rectangle rect;
        public Problem problem;
        public ProblemBox(Problem problem)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(0, 309, 244, 30);
            this.problem = problem;
        }
        public void move()
        {
            rect.Y -= 1;
        }
        public void draw(Graphics g)
        {

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, rect);
            g.DrawString(problem.problem + "=" + problem.answer, new Font("Times New Roman", 12.0f), Brushes.DarkBlue, new PointF(rect.X + 5, rect.Y + 5));
        }


    }
    #endregion


     public Problem CreateProblem() {
        char op = '+';
        int a = rand.Next(20), b = rand.Next(20), c;
        switch (rand.Next(4)) { 
            case 2:
                c = a - b;
                op = '-';
                break;
            case 3:
                c = a * b;
                op = '*';
                break;
            case 4:
                c = a / b;
                op = '/';
                break;
            default:
                c = a + b;
                op = '+';
                break;
        }
        bool isTrue = rand.Next(2) == 1;
        if (!isTrue) {
            c += 1 + (10 - rand.Next(20));

        }

        return new Problem(Type.Basic, String.Concat(a + ""+op +""+ b), String.Concat(c), isTrue);


    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        problems[0] = new ProblemBox(CreateProblem());
    }


    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)//Tick
    {
            ProblemBox temp = null;
            if (problems[0].rect.Y < 279)
            {
                temp = new ProblemBox(CreateProblem());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    ProblemBox temp2 = problems[i];
                    problems[i] = temp;
                    temp = temp2;
                }
                if (problems[i] != null)
                {
                    problems[i].move();
                    problems[i].draw(e.Graphics);
                }

            }
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            DrawingPanel.Invalidate();
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the PictureBox instead of a Panel. Just an idea, since I remember it brought less issues.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to have

```
 Thread.Sleep(20);
 DrawingPanel.Invalidate();
```

inside `Paint` method. Try to avoid them and behavior may dramatically improved.

Comment: I removed them, set up a loop in another method to update the graphics, still the same flickering

Comment: You are talking about double buffering: did you implement it ? And another again. Try to not use Paint *event*, but paint *override*. And try to not redraw *background* of control. It's hard to suggest something practical in these cases, but these steps are more common in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

As Tigran already said, you problem is what you do not finishing repaint, which could be easily solve with something like:

```
        (new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { DrawingPanel.Invalidate(); });
        })).Start();
```

However, flickering can also occurs due to slow repainting (or rather say - not fast enough). Solution in that case if pretty simple - do not draw onto screen directly (use doublebuffering).

If you need some functionality from standard component, then you *must* create your own component and call it appropriately. Using `Panel` for something what has nothing to do for what `Panel` is intended for - is bad.

Here is a good starter:

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
    public class MyControl : PictureBox
    {
            public MyControl() 
            {
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                // ...
            }
    }
```